# FIxed effects with plm, problem with NaNs

Tags: r, statistics, plm

I am trying to run a time-fixed effects regression with plm using the wbstats library. I have attached an image of the dataset for reference. I am rather new to this.

Model:

```
AfricaTotal <- plm(IndustryGDP ~ CurrentImports + AgriProd + factor(date), data = AfricaVariables, index="country")
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Here is the dataset. Is it an indexing issue?

[image: Dataset]

Comment: Without reproducible code, this will be hard to tell. A guess: it seems like you have only 16 observations and your screenshot of the data shows only one country and few obs while you want to estimate relatively many coefficients leaving no degrees of freedom left for std. error estimation. (another thing: if you want to estimate a two-way effect model, use `effect = "twoways"`).

Comment: Your model is misspecified. You should carefully read `plm` docs, also see discussion in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77588836/6574038) comments.

Comment: run ```dput(AfricaVariables)``` get sample data and paste it in your post.